# Modifying an XAML file

Tags: c#, regex, xml, xaml

I need to write a small console application that takes an XAML file as a parameter, and then makes a copy of it with 2 modifications:

1) All `Text` attributes are set to the string "example" (not on every tag, only where they were actually set to something else)

2) All tags that contain the attribute `Header`, will have a header template inside the tag instead. For example, this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="example">
    <!-- Some other stuff... -->
</GridViewColumn>
```

Should be changed to this:

```
<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="example"/>
       </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I was thinking of using Regex for the logic, but I want to know if there's an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using proper XML parser to modify XML would be more robust, because decent XML parser will never produce non [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134494/is-there-a-difference-between-valid-xml-and-well-formed-xml) XML, besides [regex is not the tool for parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la) in general.

Because you haven't started anything with any XML parser -or looks like so-, the following is just for the sake of illustration of how this can be done using XML parser, [LINQ-to-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to be specific.

Consider the following XAML and predefined data template :

```
var xaml = @"<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text='not example'/>
    <!-- Some other stuff... -->
    <GridViewColumn Header='example'>
        <!-- Some other stuff... -->
    </GridViewColumn>
</StackPanel>";
var templateXaml = @"<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text='example'/>
</DataTemplate>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xaml); //or load from file: XDocument.Load("path-to-XAML.xaml");
var template = XElement.Parse(templateXaml);
```

To apply modification no.1, you can simply do as follow :

```
foreach (var attr in doc.Descendants().Attributes("Text").Where(o => o.Value != "example"))
{
    attr.Value = "example";
}
```

and the following for modification no.2 :

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants().Where(o => o.Attribute("Header") != null))
{
    //delete all existing content
    element.DescendantNodes().Remove();
    //add new content element named "ParentElementName.HeaderTemplate"
    element.Add(new XElement(element.Name.LocalName + ".HeaderTemplate", template));
}
//print the modified XDocument (or save to file instead)
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

**<kbd>[Dotnetfiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/415A1n)</kbd>**

**console output :**

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Text="example" />
  <!-- Some other stuff... -->
  <GridViewColumn Header="example">
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="example" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
</StackPanel>
```